# Autoincrement with H2

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a Springboot application that uses Spring Data. For test purposes only, I use an embedded H2 DB and load some initial data through a data.sql file. My entity are annotated with

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

The problem I'm facing: for the generation of the ids (when I persist some objects), the id-values already used in my initial data (in data.sql) are NOT taken into consideration. As a result it comes to conflict, since it can happen that Hibernate try to use an Id already used. A solution would be to change the GenerationType into `IDENTITY`, but i'm reluctant to do so, since in production i would prefer having GenerationType.AUTO.

What is best practices to handle this?

Comment: Why do you prefer `AUTO` over `IDENTITY`.  It seems to me that an identity/auto increment column is what you need here.

Comment: In production i'm using a postgreSQL DB, and i was a bit afraid of having a mess with postgres If I use IDENTITY.

Comment: Well I think the better strategy is to let Postgres worry about managing the column.  Hibernate is just a thin layer in Java, sitting on top of JDBC, which in turn sits on top of your database.

Comment: ok thanks, i will switch to IDENTITY then

Comment: Use a wraper class (Integer, Long) in this way hibernate will use a null value and the bd will create the next id. hibernate automatically will load the created value

Comment: using AUTO gave similar issue , but on using IDENTITY i got ```h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed```

finally  SEQUENCE  worked

Answer (score 5):

Tim Biegeleisen seemed to already have convinced you: Use `IDENTITY` which seems to work in both cases.

The alternative I would recommend nowadays is to use [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) with Postgres in the test and drop H2.

Comment: Thanks, it seems interessant indeed and i will consider giving it a try for my next project.